# Should Repositories return IQueryable?

Tags: architecture, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have been seeing a lot of projects that have repositories that return instances of `IQueryable`. This allows additional filters and sorting can be performed on the `IQueryable` by other code, which translates to different SQL being generated. I am curious where this pattern came from and whether it is a good idea.

My biggest concern is that an `IQueryable` is a promise to hit the database some time later, when it is enumerated. This means that an error would be thrown outside of the repository. This could mean an Entity Framework exception is thrown in a different layer of the application.

I have also run into issues with Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) in the past (especially when using transactions) and this approach sounds like it would lead to this happening more often.

I have always called `ToList` or `ToArray` at the end of each of my LINQ expressions to make sure the database is hit before leaving the repository code.

I am wondering if returning `IQueryable` could be useful as a building block for a data layer. I have seen some pretty extravagant code with one repository calling another repository to build an even bigger `IQueryable`.

Comment: What would be the difference if the db was not available at the time of the deferred query execution vs the time of query construction? Consuming code would have to deal with that situation regardless.

Comment: Interesting question, but it will probably be hard to answer. A simple search shows a fairly heated debate about your question: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=repository+return+iqueryable

Comment: It all comes down to whether you want to allow your clients to add Linq clauses that could benefit from deferred execution.  If they add a `where` clause to a deferred `IQueryable`, you only have to send *that* data over the wire, not the entire result set.

Comment: If you are using repository pattern - no, you should not return IQueryable. Here's a [nice why](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/).

Comment: @SteveEvers There is a huge difference. If an exception is thrown in my repository, I can wrap it with a data-layer-specific exception type. If it happens later on, I have to capture the original exception type there. The closer I am to the source of the exception, the more likely I'll know what caused it. This is important for creating meaningful error messages. IMHO, allowing an EF-specific exception to leave my repository is a violation of encapsulation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see why the repository can't have an extra method for each variation. Sure, it gets big and nasty, but it might promote reuse if two or more pieces of code apply the same filters.

Comment: @SteveEvers Another thought I just had was to create an `IQueryable` that could wrap EF-specific exceptions for me. This would be fairly easy to write.

Comment: @TravisParks: You can. If you have something like Dynamic Linq or Predicate Builder, you might not even need a method for each combination of filters.

Comment: A related question I posted on SO years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677722/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-for-business-logic-or-dal-return-types

Comment: I've considered this heavily and have decided (in my own code) to avoid using IQuerable when a clear alternative is available, but to use it when it's not convenient to avoid it. For example, a filterable grid in JavaScript where the queries are literally user defined and so varied that anything else would either restrict the user or cause performance issues. In these cases, you should still think about how that interface maps to the underlying code. Pragmatism wins in this area.

Comment: It might also help to indicate that the object is "hot" so that developers consuming the interface understand they should be cautious of deferred execution and possible exceptions when realising the collection.

Comment: I know it's an old question but still relevant to these days. I just want to point out that `AsEnumerable` isn't going to hit the database, it would just cast the object from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`, but the underlying structure would still be `IQueryable` (which means the SQL query has still not happened).

Comment: @LionGod8 Good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 59):

Returning IQueryable will definitely afford more flexibility to the consumers of the repository. It puts the responsibility of narrowing results off to the client, which naturally can both be a benefit and a crutch.

On the good side, you won't need to be creating tons of repository methods (at least on this layer) — GetAllActiveItems, GetAllNonActiveItems, etc — to get the data you want. Depending on your preference, again, this could be good or bad. You **will** (/should) need to define behavioral contracts which your implementations adhere to, but where that goes is up to you.

So you could put the gritty retrieval logic outside the repository and let it be used however the user wants. So exposing IQueryable gives the most flexibility and allows for efficient querying as opposed to in-memory filtering, etc, and *could* reduce the need for making a ton of specific data fetching methods.

On the other hand, now you have given your users a shotgun. They can do things which you may not have intended (overusing .include(), doing heavy heavy queries and doing *in-memory* filtering in their respective implementations, etc), which would basically side-step the layering and behavioral controls because you have given full access.

So depending on the team, their experience, the size of the app, the overall layering and architecture … it depends :-\

Comment: Note that you could, if you wanted to work for it, return your IQueryable, which in turn calls the DB, but adds layering and behavioral controls.

Comment: @psr Could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @TravisParks - IQueryable doesn't have to be implemented by the DB, you can write IQueryable classes yourself - it's just pretty hard.  So you could write an IQueryable wrapper around a database IQueryable, and have your IQueryable limit full access to the underlying DB.  But this is hard enough that I wouldn't expect it to be widely done.

Comment: IQueryable.Include is an extension method for System.Data.Entity, I don't think it should be considered in this particular aspect of IQueryable as you can use IQuerable without exposing it to the consuming code.

Comment: Note that even when you don't return IQueryables, you can still prevent having to make many methods (GetAllActiveItems, GetAllNonActiveItems, etc) by simply passing an `Expression<Func<Foo,bool>>` to your method. This parameters can be passed to the `Where` method directly, thus enabling the consumer to choose their filter without needing direct access to the IQueryable<Foo>.

Comment: I submitted this answer over 5 years ago now, and @Flater, I agree that the Expression /  Predicate builder idea is neat. I still use and expose IQueryable in my implementations, and LINQ is still as cool as ice, I'd caution about making any system too rigid until the system has stabilized and proven itself. Exposing iQueryable would lend itself to change, while rigid "contracts" at too low a level could have far-reaching effects causing pain when refactoring is necessary.

Comment: @hanzolo: Depends on what you mean with refactoring. It's true that changing the  design (e.g. adding new fields or changing the relations) is more of a pain when you have a layered and loosely coupled codebase; but refactoring is _less_ of a pain when you only need to change one layer. It all depends on whether you expect to redesign the application, or whether you're simply refactoring your implementation of the same basic architecture. I would still advocate loose coupling in either case but you're not wrong that it adds to the refactoring when changing core domain concepts.

Comment: @Flater - I agree 100%, i just meant dont over engineer something that's still in flux, or at least attempt to ensure that there's enough flexibility in design to "morph" the code as the system is developed. There's nothing worse than building a beautiful purposed built structure, and then learning you have to make it do something the original design didn't anticipate or intend to do, so identifying the "flux-ness" to determine the "rigidity" should be something to try to understand

Answer (score 36):

Exposing IQueryable to public interfaces is not a good practice.
The reason is fundamental: you cannot provide IQueryable realisation as it is said to be.

Public interface is a contract between provider and clients. And in most cases there is an expectation of full implementation. IQueryable is a cheat:

1. IQueryable is nearly impossible to implement. And currently there is no proper solution.
   Even Entity Framework has lots of [UnsupportedExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414058/why-does-ef-4-1-not-support-complex-queries-as-well-as-linq-to-sql).
2. Today Queryable providers have large dependance on infrastructure. Sharepoint has its own partial implementation and My SQL provider has distinct partial implementation.

[Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) gives us clear representation by layering, and, most important, independence of realisation. So we can change in future data source.

The question is "**Should there be possibility of data source substitution?**".

If tomorrow part of the data can be moved to SAP services, NoSQL data base, or simply to text files, can we guaranty proper implementation of IQueryable interface?

([more](http://developersdev.blogspot.ru/2013/12/iquerable-drawbacks-repository-pattern.html) good points about why this is bad practice)

Comment: This answer does not stand on its own without consulting the volatile external link. Consider summarizing at least the key points made by the external resource, and try to keep personal opinion out of your answer ("worst idea I've heard"). Also consider removing the code snippet that seems unrelated to anything IQueryable.

Comment: Thank you @LarsViklund, the answer is updated with examples and problem description

Answer (score 21):

Realistically, you've got three alternatives if you want deferred execution:

- Do it this way - expose an `IQueryable`.
- Implement a structure that exposes specific methods for specific filters or "questions".  (`GetCustomersInAlaskaWithChildren`, below)
- Implement a structure that exposes a strongly-typed filter/sort/page API and builds the `IQueryable` internally.

I prefer the third (though I've helped colleagues implement the second as well), but there's obviously some setup and maintenance involved.  (T4 to the rescue!)

*Edit*: To clear up the confusion surrounding what I'm talking about, consider the following example stolen from [IQueryable Can Kill Your Dog, Steal Your Wife, Kill Your Will to Live, etc.](https://web.archive.org/web/20110313023347/http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc)

In the scenario where you would expose something like this:

```
public class CustomerRepo : IRepo 
{ 
     private DataContext ct; 
     public Customer GetCustomerById(int id) { ... } 
     public Customer[] GetCustomersInAlaskaWithChildren() { ... } 
}
```

the API I'm talking about would let you expose a method that would let you express `GetCustomersInAlaskaWithChildren` (or any other combination of criteria) in a flexible manner, and the repo would execute it as an IQueryable and return the results to you.  But the important thing is that it runs inside the repository layer, so it still takes advantage of deferred execution.  Once you get the results back, you can still LINQ-to-objects on it to your heart's content.

Another advantage of an approach like this is that, because they're POCO classes, this repository can live behind a web or WCF service; it can be exposed to AJAX or other callers that don't know the first thing about LINQ.

Comment: So you'd build a query API to substitute for .NET's built in query API?

Comment: If I didn't want to expose the built-in query API, yes.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as what Ozz said...that was pretty harsh. But to me IQueryable is part of the framework. Implementing an alternative to avoid using what the framework provides seems excessive to me.

Comment: @MikeBrown The point of this question - and my answer - is that you want to expose the *behavior* or the *advantages* of `IQueryable` **without exposing the `IQueryable` itself**.  How are you going to do that, with the built-in API?

Comment: That's a very good tautology. You haven't explained why you want to avoid that. Heck WCF Data Services exposes IQueryable across the wire. I'm not trying to pick on you, I'm just not understanding this aversion to IQueryable people seem to have.

Comment: If you're just going to use an IQueryable, then why would you even use a repository?  Repositories are intended to hide implementation details.  (Also, WCF Data Services is quite a bit newer than most of the solutions I've worked on in the past 4 years that used a repository like this...  So it's not likely that they'll be updated anytime soon just to make use of a shiny new toy.)

Comment: @MikeBrown http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Comment: Work on one large-scale team website that goes down in the middle of the night because a junior programmer got giddy with an IQueryable and you'll understand the need immediately.

Comment: My point being, not all design patterns and lengths to go to are appropriate for all scenarios, project scales or team-sizes. 

GetCustomersInAlaskaWithChildren while leaving the connection open to lazy-load on the consumer end IS very cool - but you still run into the possibility of the above scenario. Someone can potentially pull the whole database down ala joins for a what should have been quick lookup...

Comment: Nothing in a responsitory pattery that returns a list prevents someone from pulling down the entire database.  Worse over a repository pattern makes it more likely as they will just pull the data down then do an in  memory linq to objects query to filter additional data.

Comment: @MatthewWhited That seems like a team discipline thing. Stuff like adding new methods to the repository or specialized repositories should be talked about in Developer guidelines on a project. If your developers are just writing code without considering the consequences, then you have a culture problem. The proper response would be for the developer to either implement the new method to get the scoped data themselves, or bring it up as a road block in the scrum meeting in the morning (or whatever system of communication you use) to get the right person to resolve it for them.

Comment: I don't disagree... but that also defeats the purpose of LINQ.

Answer (score 9):

There really is only one legitimate answer: it depends on how the repository is to be used.

At one extreme your repository is a very thin wrapper around a DBContext so you can inject a veneer of testability around a database-driven app. There really is no real world expectation that this might be used in a disconnected manner without a LINQ friendly DB behind it because your CRUD app ain't ever gonna need that. Then sure, why not use IQueryable? I would probably prefer IEnumarable as you get most of the benefits [read: delayed execution] and it don't feel as dirty.

Unless you are sitting at that extreme I would try hard to take advantage of the spirit of the repository pattern and return appropriate materialized collections that don't have an implication of an underlying database connection.

Comment: Regarding returning `IEnumerable`, it's important to note that `((IEnumerable<T>)query).LastOrDefault()` is very different from `query.LastOrDefault()` (presuming `query` is an `IQueryable`). So, it only makes sense to return `IEnumerable` if you're going to iterate through all elements anyway.

Answer (score 8):

```
 > Should Repositories return IQueryable?
```

**NO** if you want to do testdriven development/unittesting because there is no easy way to create a mock repository to test your businesslogic (= repository-consumer) in isolation from database or other IQueryable provider.

Comment: But what should they then return?

Answer (score 7):

What I've seen done (and what I'm implementing myself) is the following:

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey> where TEntity : IEntity<TKey>
{
    void Create(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Get(TKey key);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TKey id);
}
```

What this allows you to do is to have the flexibility of doing an `IQueryable.Where(a => a.SomeFilter)` query on your repo by doing `concreteRepo.GetAll(a => a.SomeFilter)` without exposing any LINQy business.

Comment: I've seen this elsewhere.  Does this help?

Answer (score 6):

From a pure architecture standpoint, IQueryable is a leaky abstraction. As a generality, it provides the user with too much power. That being said, there are places where it makes sense. If you are using OData, IQueryable makes it extremely easy to provide an endpoint that is easily filterable, sortable, groupable... etc. I actually prefer to create DTO's that my entities map onto and the IQueryable returns the DTO instead. That way I pre-filter my data and really only use the IQueryable method to allow client customization of the results.

Answer (score 6):

I've faced such choice as well.

So, let's summarize positive and negative sides:

**Positives:**

- Flexibility. It's definitely flexible and convenient to allow client side to build custom queries with just one repository method

**Negatives:**

- *Untestable*. (you will be actually testing the underlying IQueryable implementation, which usually your ORM. But you should test your logic instead)
- *Blurs responsibility*. It's impossible to say, what that particular method of your repository does. Actually, it is a god-method, that can return anything you like in your entire database
- *Unsafe*. With no restrictions on what can be queried by this repository method, in some cases such implementations can be unsafe from security point.
- *Caching problems* (or, to be generic, any pre- or post-processing problems). It is generally unwise to, for example, cache everything in your application. You will try to cache something, that cause your database significant load. But how to do that, if you have only one repository method, that clients use to issue virtually any query against the database?
- *Logging problems*. Logging something at the repository layer will make you inspect IQueryable first to check should this particular call be logged or not.

I would recommend against using this approach. Consider instead creating several [Specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) and implement repository methods, that can query database using those. [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) is a great way to encapsulate a set of conditions.

Answer (score 5):

I think that exposing the IQueryable on your repository is perfectly acceptable during the initial phases of development. There are UI tools that can work with IQueryable directly and handle sorting, filtering, grouping, etc.

That being said, I think that just exposing crud on the repository and calling it a day is irresponsible. Having useful operations and query helpers for common queries allows you to centralize the logic for a query while also exposing a smaller interface surface to consumers of the repository.

For the first few iterations of a project, exposing IQueryable publicly on the repository allows for quicker growth. Before the first full release, I'd recommend making the query operation private or protected and bringing the wild queries under one roof.